# How to set a particular position as default in spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am getting list of data from server and setting in spinner through setAdapter, but what data is coming on 3rd position  I want to set that as default(0th position). Ex.  {Mango, Banana, apple} ; in spinner apple should be default instead of Mango

```
         else if 
             (mListener.getSelection().get(0).
              getGenLovs().get(i).getLovId().
              equalsIgnoreCase(File_Key.AB_CUST_TITLE)) 
             {
                        binding.spinTitle.setAdapter(new 
                        GenLovsSpinner(getContext(), 
                        mListener.getSelection().get(0). 
                        getGenLovs().get(i).getValDes()));
                    }
```

I have tried this

```
             String cls= 
             String.valueOf(mListener.getSelection().
             get(0).getGenLovs().get(i).getValDes().get(3));
             binding.spinTitle.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(cls),true);
```

Here when I am using above code I am getting NumberFormatException

Answer (score 1):

```
binding.spinTitle.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(cls),true);
```

use this insted of above line

```
binding.spinTitle.setSelection(Integer.valueOf(cls));
```

Answer (score 1):

See you are setting up any list or array to spinner adapter.
If you want to set particular as default then try this for example :- 
Let you are setting `dataList` to spinner adapter 
after `setAdapter()` for selection

either `spinner.setSelection(dataList.indexOf("apple"),true)` or 
`spinner.setSelection(2,true)` as your third data has index 2

Answer (score 0):

Just give `binding.spinTitle.setSelection(2);`

Comment: before setting adapter ?

Comment: Just after setAdapter

Comment: If I am setting adapter then already it is set then how can it  change to default value?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
Use the following: spinnerObject.setSelection(position).
```